# Remove server response header

Tags: headers

I'm fairly new to WP/PHP and I'm trying to remove the server response header in functions.php. I've been trying use something like this but it doesn't work:

```
add_filter('wp_headers', function($headers) {

unset($headers['server']);

return $headers;

});
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: This header is most likely set by the webserver, not the application. You'll have to remove it with a custom .htaccess or NGINX configuration

Comment: The filter may not work if your site is serving cached pages.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.